# Matlab: iterative loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, wave

I have a wav signal that I read in samples in a buffer s. I want to save in a 
new buffer x the samples that are in 10 position, 20, 30..110 position. 
How can I do this? I must write a for loop but how can I write the contator?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by buffer, but here's how you'd get that info out of an array. Given `s = 1:107`, you could get the elements starting at position `10` by issuing the command:

```
b = s(10:10:end);
```

Now, `b` equals `10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to save in a new buffer x the samples that are in 10 position, 20, 30..110 position. How can I do this?

```
x = s(10:10:110);
```

This would work too:

```
x = s(10*(1:11));
```

Houstanb's solution is best if you want every 10th sample from your buffer s, and not just up to 110 as you state.

> I must write a for loop but how can I write the contator?

If you ***must*** write a for loop then you can try this:

```
x = nan(1,11);
for k=1:11
    x(k) = s(k*10);
end
```

But this is not a great solution from a MATLAB perspective, where vectorization is preferred.